# unexpected behaviour of content manager installer (SDLTridion2011SP1)

Tags: tridion

We were skipped few modules such as outbound emails and Community builder etc. during the first installation of Tridion 2011 SP1 and now we want to run the installer in repair mode to add these modules.
When we run the content manager installer (SDLTridion2011SP1) below screen appears -

[image]

We are expecting options for uninstall and repair here.

Could anybody please explore us  the reason of this unexpected behaviour of installer.

Comment: Have you contacted the vendor about this?

Comment: You are right to expect those options. 
Are you choosing "Modify" from the "Programs and Features" menu?

Comment: @ Peter , no i am not trying to modify it from  windows  program and feature.

Comment: @John , we will certaily contact to vender in case no resolution here.

Comment: @RamS No offense, but you're doing it wrong: This is a bug or missing feature in software you paid for. You should contact your vendor for support ***first*** -- that's why you give them money. Server Fault is not "Tridion Tech Support" and the majority of us haven't even used it, all we can offer are generic suggestions...

Answer (score 2):

You should run the installer using the Modify mode and not Repair repair. The repair mode will just re-install the current options. Also make sure you run the installer using the same administrative user that you did the original install with.